# No output running /usr/sbin/crond in a Docker alpine container?

Tags: docker, cron

My simple `Dockerfile` seems to work, however I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong. The **container log is empty** (`docker logs -f <container id>`).

The `crond` command is running in foreground (`-f`), so why I can't see any ouput?

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --update --no-cache lftp mariadb-client

CMD ["/usr/sbin/crond", "-l", "2", "-f"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

Your Dockerfile.

```sh
docker build --tag=60404556 --file=Dockerfile .

# One terminal
docker run --rm --interactive --tty --name=crond 60404556
crond[1]: crond (busybox 1.31.1) started, log level 2
crond[1]: user:root entry:*/15  *   *   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/15min
crond[1]: user:root entry:0 *   *   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/hourly
crond[1]: user:root entry:0 2   *   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/daily
crond[1]: user:root entry:0 3   *   *   6   run-parts /etc/periodic/weekly
crond[1]: user:root entry:0 5   1   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/monthly
...

# Another term
docker container logs --follow crond
crond[1]: crond (busybox 1.31.1) started, log level 2
crond[1]: user:root entry:*/15  *   *   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/15min
crond[1]: user:root entry:0 *   *   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/hourly
crond[1]: user:root entry:0 2   *   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/daily
crond[1]: user:root entry:0 3   *   *   6   run-parts /etc/periodic/weekly
crond[1]: user:root entry:0 5   1   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/monthly
...
```

Comment: You are getting the output from crond?